# Выпадающий список в Laravel5

Tags: laravel

Привет всем!

Вот возникла проблема с Ларой. Нужно получить выпадающий список в html форме, где данные из этого списка берутся из базы данных.

[image: Вот пример списка, который я хочу получить:]

Начну с определений:

```
mainpage.blade.php - блейд форма html в ларе

Drop.php - моя таблица (class). 

$claims - переменная, в которую должны сохранятся переменные.
```

Вот код(не рабочий):

Route

```
Route::post('/add', 'MainController@index'); //вызов метода из моего контроллера
```

Drop.php

```
class Drop extends BaseModel
{
    public $table = 'claim_type'; // таблица в БД

}
```

MainController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Main;
use App\Drop;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $claims = Drop::all(); // значения из таблицы в переменную
        dd($claims);
        return view('mainpage', compact( 'id', 'type')); // возвращаем на мою страницу значения id и type.
}
```

**Код ошибки:
(2/2) ErrorException
Undefined variable: claims**

Кого смущает моя таблица Drop - она работает, я задекларировал ее как public $table = 'claim_type';

С базой и подключением пролем нет, другая часть кода (рабочая) используется для ввода данных в БД

Мои доводы:

*"Я думаю что проблема с формой хтмл, поскольку нет других ошибок. Так как БД подключена и тестирована, проблема конкретно в извленении и вывода на экран. Как видим из кода ошибки - переменная, в которую передаются даннные не видится формой. Скорее всего я провафлил где-то функцию, либо неверный роутинг...."*

Как это сделать, подскажите!

Просмотрел кучу ресурсов, потратил целый день и ничего не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не предоставили листинг шаблона. Но из вашего кода можно судить о том что вы не передали значение $claims в шаблон:
`return view('mainpage', compact( 'id', 'type'));`
Попробуйте исправьте на:
`return view('mainpage', compact( 'id', 'type', 'claims'));`.
И посмотрите на результат.